# How to host a html using sd card

Tags: webserver, esp8266, sd-card

i wanna host a webserver from a sd card using ESP8266. i look through the github library SDWebServer, and i tried the code it came out following error

error: 'class String' has no member named 'clear' and the line of code "path.clear();" is causing this error

Can anyone help to solve or anyone has better example code to share with me?

```
/*  SDWebServer - Example WebServer with SD Card backend for esp8266
  Copyright (c) 2015 Hristo Gochkov. All rights reserved.
  This file is part of the ESP8266WebServer library for Arduino environment.
  This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
  version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
  This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
  Lesser General Public License for more details.
  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
  License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
  Have a FAT Formatted SD Card connected to the SPI port of the ESP8266
  The web root is the SD Card root folder
  File extensions with more than 3 charecters are not supported by the SD Library
  File Names longer than 8 charecters will be truncated by the SD library, so keep filenames shorter
  index.htm is the default index (works on subfolders as well)
  upload the contents of SdRoot to the root of the SDcard and access the editor by going to http://esp8266sd.local/edit
*/
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

#define DBG_OUTPUT_PORT Serial

#ifndef STASSID
#define STASSID "your-ssid"
#define STAPSK  "your-password"
#endif

const char* ssid = STASSID;
const char* password = STAPSK;
const char* host = "esp8266sd";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

static bool hasSD = false;
File uploadFile;


void returnOK() {
  server.send(200, "text/plain", "");
}

void returnFail(String msg) {
  server.send(500, "text/plain", msg + "\r\n");
}

bool loadFromSdCard(String path) {
  String dataType = "text/plain";
  if (path.endsWith("/")) {
    path += "index.htm";
  }

  if (path.endsWith(".src")) {
    path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("."));
  } else if (path.endsWith(".htm")) {
    dataType = "text/html";
  } else if (path.endsWith(".css")) {
    dataType = "text/css";
  } else if (path.endsWith(".js")) {
    dataType = "application/javascript";
  } else if (path.endsWith(".png")) {
    dataType = "image/png";
  } else if (path.endsWith(".gif")) {
    dataType = "image/gif";
  } else if (path.endsWith(".jpg")) {
    dataType = "image/jpeg";
  } else if (path.endsWith(".ico")) {
    dataType = "image/x-icon";
  } else if (path.endsWith(".xml")) {
    dataType = "text/xml";
  } else if (path.endsWith(".pdf")) {
    dataType = "application/pdf";
  } else if (path.endsWith(".zip")) {
    dataType = "application/zip";
  }

  File dataFile = SD.open(path.c_str());
  if (dataFile.isDirectory()) {
    path += "/index.htm";
    dataType = "text/html";
    dataFile = SD.open(path.c_str());
  }

  if (!dataFile) {
    return false;
  }

  if (server.hasArg("download")) {
    dataType = "application/octet-stream";
  }

  if (server.streamFile(dataFile, dataType) != dataFile.size()) {
    DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.println("Sent less data than expected!");
  }

  dataFile.close();
  return true;
}

void handleFileUpload() {
  if (server.uri() != "/edit") {
    return;
  }
  HTTPUpload& upload = server.upload();
  if (upload.status == UPLOAD_FILE_START) {
    if (SD.exists((char *)upload.filename.c_str())) {
      SD.remove((char *)upload.filename.c_str());
    }
    uploadFile = SD.open(upload.filename.c_str(), FILE_WRITE);
    DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.print("Upload: START, filename: "); DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.println(upload.filename);
  } else if (upload.status == UPLOAD_FILE_WRITE) {
    if (uploadFile) {
      uploadFile.write(upload.buf, upload.currentSize);
    }
    DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.print("Upload: WRITE, Bytes: "); DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.println(upload.currentSize);
  } else if (upload.status == UPLOAD_FILE_END) {
    if (uploadFile) {
      uploadFile.close();
    }
    DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.print("Upload: END, Size: "); DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.println(upload.totalSize);
  }
}

void deleteRecursive(String path) {
  File file = SD.open((char *)path.c_str());
  if (!file.isDirectory()) {
    file.close();
    SD.remove((char *)path.c_str());
    return;
  }

  file.rewindDirectory();
  while (true) {
    File entry = file.openNextFile();
    if (!entry) {
      break;
    }
    String entryPath = path + "/" + entry.name();
    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
      entry.close();
      deleteRecursive(entryPath);
    } else {
      entry.close();
      SD.remove((char *)entryPath.c_str());
    }
    yield();
  }

  SD.rmdir((char *)path.c_str());
  file.close();
}

void handleDelete() {
  if (server.args() == 0) {
    return returnFail("BAD ARGS");
  }
  String path = server.arg(0);
  if (path == "/" || !SD.exists((char *)path.c_str())) {
    returnFail("BAD PATH");
    return;
  }
  deleteRecursive(path);
  returnOK();
}

void handleCreate() {
  if (server.args() == 0) {
    return returnFail("BAD ARGS");
  }
  String path = server.arg(0);
  if (path == "/" || SD.exists((char *)path.c_str())) {
    returnFail("BAD PATH");
    return;
  }

  if (path.indexOf('.') > 0) {
    File file = SD.open((char *)path.c_str(), FILE_WRITE);
    if (file) {
      file.write((const char *)0);
      file.close();
    }
  } else {
    SD.mkdir((char *)path.c_str());
  }
  returnOK();
}

void printDirectory() {
  if (!server.hasArg("dir")) {
    return returnFail("BAD ARGS");
  }
  String path = server.arg("dir");
  if (path != "/" && !SD.exists((char *)path.c_str())) {
    return returnFail("BAD PATH");
  }
  File dir = SD.open((char *)path.c_str());
  path.clear();
  if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
    dir.close();
    return returnFail("NOT DIR");
  }
  dir.rewindDirectory();
  server.setContentLength(CONTENT_LENGTH_UNKNOWN);
  server.send(200, "text/json", "");
  WiFiClient client = server.client();

  server.sendContent("[");
  for (int cnt = 0; true; ++cnt) {
    File entry = dir.openNextFile();
    if (!entry) {
      break;
    }

    String output;
    if (cnt > 0) {
      output = ',';
    }

    output += "{\"type\":\"";
    output += (entry.isDirectory()) ? "dir" : "file";
    output += "\",\"name\":\"";
    output += entry.name();
    output += "\"";
    output += "}";
    server.sendContent(output);
    entry.close();
  }
  server.sendContent("]");
  server.sendContent(""); // Terminate the HTTP chunked transmission with a 0-length chunk
  dir.close();
}

void handleNotFound() {
  if (hasSD && loadFromSdCard(server.uri())) {
    return;
  }
  String message = "SDCARD Not Detected\n\n";
  message += "URI: ";
  message += server.uri();
  message += "\nMethod: ";
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET) ? "GET" : "POST";
  message += "\nArguments: ";
  message += server.args();
  message += "\n";
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < server.args(); i++) {
    message += " NAME:" + server.argName(i) + "\n VALUE:" + server.arg(i) + "\n";
  }
  server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
  DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.print(message);
}

void setup(void) {
  DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.begin(115200);
  DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.setDebugOutput(true);
  DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.print("\n");
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.print("Connecting to ");
  DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.println(ssid);

  // Wait for connection
  uint8_t i = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && i++ < 20) {//wait 10 seconds
    delay(500);
  }
  if (i == 21) {
    DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.print("Could not connect to");
    DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.println(ssid);
    while (1) {
      delay(500);
    }
  }
  DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.print("Connected! IP address: ");
  DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.println(WiFi.localIP());

  if (MDNS.begin(host)) {
    MDNS.addService("http", "tcp", 80);
    DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.println("MDNS responder started");
    DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.print("You can now connect to http://");
    DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.print(host);
    DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.println(".local");
  }


  server.on("/list", HTTP_GET, printDirectory);
  server.on("/edit", HTTP_DELETE, handleDelete);
  server.on("/edit", HTTP_PUT, handleCreate);
  server.on("/edit", HTTP_POST, []() {
    returnOK();
  }, handleFileUpload);
  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);

  server.begin();
  DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.println("HTTP server started");

  if (SD.begin(SS)) {
    DBG_OUTPUT_PORT.println("SD Card initialized.");
    hasSD = true;
  }
}

void loop(void) {
  server.handleClient();
  MDNS.update();
}
```

Comment: That error would have included a line number. You wanna share that too?

Comment: @romkey its under void prindDirectory function, line 9

Answer (score 1):

The code compiles without warnings and errors. Used environment:
Arduino IDE v 1.8.13
ESP8266 community edition v 2.6.3
windows machine

My guess is old ESP or Arduino libs - versions above.
The code is ok as a starter for own projects.
One starting tip:
Replace all Strings with char functionsor you will have stability problems later on (Heap fragmentation)

Answer (score 0):

you have to  remove "hasSD &&" from ***void handleNotFound*** function.

it worked for me.